# Using NSView instances as NSDictionary keys?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsview

I'm trying to create a semi-complex set of view animations (think an animated version of an `NSMatrix` form, where rows slide around as other rows are added or removed), and to build the animation I'm making a little helper class.

There I have to keep track of the different views, their ordered indices, and few some other values associated with their animations.

To that end, I'm using an `NSArray` instance to keep track of the ordering (indices) of the views, and I'd like to use an `NSDictionary` with the views as keys to keep track of the values (the values themselves are in nested dictionaries). I.e. I'd like to be able to do something this, for instance (pseudo code):

```
NSMutableDictionary* viewValuesDict = [NSDictionary dictionary];

// Loop thru an ordered NSArray
for( (NSView*) view in viewsArray ) {
    // Get some values we'll need later
    NSDictionary* associatedValues = [view getSomeValues];

    // ...and put them into viewValuesDict...
    [viewValuesDict setObject:associatedValues forKey:view];

    // and then things break because the NSView 'view'
    // doesn't support copyWithZone.... darn
}
```

**Problem is**, I of course can't use `NSView` instances as dictionary keys, because the keys are added using `copyWithZone`, which `NSView` does not implement.

So, what's a good way to get a unique key for an `NSView` instance? I could conceivably use `[obj description]` since the memory address you get back is a perfect UID, but of course the system has to work with any kind of `NSView` subclass that might return something else entirely, so that's no good.

Or should I maybe try something else entirely? Is there maybe some alternative to `NSDictionary`, where keys just aren't copied? Because in this case I really have no need for the keys to ever be copied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes there are occasions where you want to use a view (whether `NS` or `UI`) as the key in a dictionary.  I've come across one such situation.  I would've preferred to use `objc_setAssociatedObject`, but that requires Snow Leopard.  Boxing with `NSValue` will work, but if you need to be doing lots and lots of look ups given a view, the continual boxing and unboxing of pointers may become tedious.

There are two options to creating an `NSView => <object>` dictionary.

1. Use `NSMapTable`
2. Use `CFMutableDictionaryRef`

[`NSMapTable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) is a class introduced in 10.5 that is very similar to an `NSMutableDictionary`, except that it has extra abilities that make it work more nicely with garbage collection.  In your case, you'll probably want a map table with "weak" keys and "strong" values, but read the documentation for all the fun details.

[`CFMutableDictionaryRef`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html) is the Core Foundation equivalent of an `NSDictionary` (they are toll-free bridged), but it has some extra creation options.  You create one using `CFDictionaryCreateMutable()`, and that wants two `struct` parameters.  One is a structure that defines the memory management (and other) behavior of how to deal with the keys of the dictionary, and the other is a `struct` for defining the behavior of the values.  You can create a `CFMutableDictionaryRef` with the options of retaining the keys (instead of copying them) and then retaining the values.  Once you've done this, you can cast the `CFMutableDictionaryRef` to an `NSMutableDictionary` and use it as you'd expect, just that the keys will be retained instead of copied.

Comment: Veeeery interesting! I definitely have to try those out. As I say in another comment, I am targeting Snow Leopard, but I don't need anything to stick around for very long, so `objc_setAssociatedObject` is maybe overkill. NSMapTable and CFMutableDictionaryRef both sound like they might fit the bill perfectly however. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSMapTable` instead of `NSDictionary` (of course you'll have to be sure to manage your object lifetimes carefully if you're not using garbage collection).  [This article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/nsmaptable-more-than-nsdictionary-for.html) has a good summary of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As andyvn22 said, reorganize! But if that isn’t practical:

- If you’re targeting Snow Leopard, and the associations are likely to persist for the lifetime of the views, use `objc_setAssociatedObject()`.
- Otherwise, use `[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]` in preference to `-description`. (Like it says, it doesn’t retain the object, but your array does.)

Comment: Reorganizing could be done, but I was hoping for a shortcut :-) I am targeting Snow Leopard, but I only need the values for a very short time, so I think I'll skip `objc_setAssociatedObject()`. But `valueWithNonretainedObject:` might be the way to go. I'll try it out - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your dictionaries so that one of their values is the view; then rearrange the code so that you need not look up dictionary based on view, but rather begin either with the dictionaries, or the index (putting the dictionaries into an array), or a unique ID of your own creation (putting the dictionaries into a dictionary; the ID could be as simple as a consecutive number for each new view you begin to keep track of). Unless you're doing something very complicated and dynamic, it should be possible to avoid needing to look up information given only an `NSView`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was thinking about that too. I just figured that there had to some way of just using any ol' object as a key. It seems (to me at least) that using objects as keys would be a straightforward way of "faking" a few extra properties on an object (I wish categories would somehow let you add ivars... sigh).

Comment: Nope. Keys have really specific properties; it's what makes dictionaries effective. If you're really trying to add some additional properties to each NSView, why aren't you subclassing? That's exactly what subclasses are for!

Comment: Because the code has to function with any view you throw at it, not just specific subclasses. And besides, it's only about storing a few associated values for a very brief time (long enough to prepare the resulting NSViewAnimation, but that's it), so while I could do some object composition and wrap the NSViews, it just seemed like overkill. And anyway, NSMapTable is working out great :-)